# JavaScript : Enable button if field is filled is not automatical

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```js
function checkValid() {
  var cbChecked = $(".fakeRadio").is(":checked"); // check if checked
  var hasText = $("#email-download-document").val().length > 0; // check if it has text

  $("#document-choice-button").prop("disabled", !cbChecked || !hasText);
}

$(function() {
  checkValid(); // run it for the first time
  $(".fakeRadio").on("change", checkValid); // bind checkbox
  $("#email-download-document").on("change", checkValid) // bind textbox
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-5">
    <label for="primary">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-download-document" name="EmailDownloadDocument" placeholder="Enter email address to get document(s)">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-5">
    <input id="document-choice-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="DocumentSelected" value="{% trans 'Send to my email' %}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get your help because I have a little issue with my simple `Javascript` part and `Chrome` Browser.

With Chrome, my button is greyed out until I click outside of the field when this one is filled. I would like to enable my button when the field is automatically filled with email verification thanks to `type='email'`.

This is an example :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of *change*.

> The DOM *input* event is fired ***synchronously*** when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is changed.

```js
function checkValid() {
  var cbChecked = $(".fakeRadio").is(":checked");  // check if checked
  var hasText = $("#email-download-document").val().length > 0;  // check if it has text
  $("#document-choice-button").prop("disabled", !cbChecked || !hasText);
}

$(function () {
  checkValid(); // run it for the first time
  $(".fakeRadio").on("input", checkValid);  // bind checkbox
  $("#email-download-document").on("input", checkValid)  // bind textbox
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-5">
    <label for="primary">Fake Radio</label>
    <input type="radio" class="fakeRadio" checked>
    <label for="primary">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-download-document" name="EmailDownloadDocument"
           placeholder="Enter email address to get document(s)">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-5">
    <input id="document-choice-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="DocumentSelected"
           value="Send to my email"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work ! And thanks to you I have the exaplanation so thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 'input' event instead of 'change' event in your Javascript, to trigger the function when the user is typing into the field.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have your HTML button by default `disabled`

```
<input id="document-choice-button" type="submit" ... disabled="disabled" />
```

This way, it will load disabled without any javascript.

Then, attach a function to `keyup` event of your textbox to check if the length of the current text is greater than zero.

```
$("#email-download-document").keyup(function(){    // triggered at any keystroke
  if ($(this).val().length>0) {
    $("#document-choice-button").removeProp("disabled");      // enable the field
  } else {
     $("#document-choice-button").prop("disabled","disabled");  // disable the field
  }
});
```

PS: This will make the button enabled/disabled as you are typing or clearing text from the textfield. If you would like to only disable/re-enable after you have exited the textfield, then you will need to attach the function to the `change` event

```
$("#email-download-document").change(function(){   //triggered after leaving textbox
  if ($(this).val().length>0) {
    $("#document-choice-button").removeProp("disabled");
  } else {
     $("#document-choice-button").prop("disabled","disabled");
  }
});
```

```js
$("#email-download-document").keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length>0) {
    $("#document-choice-button").removeProp("disabled");
  } else {
     $("#document-choice-button").prop("disabled","disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-5">
    <label for="primary">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-download-document" name="EmailDownloadDocument" placeholder="Enter email address to get document(s)">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-5">
    <input id="document-choice-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="DocumentSelected" value="{% trans 'Send to my email' %}" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</div>
```